# Gmap clustered item title in pop window

Tags: views, nodes, google-maps

I'm using Gmap with the Clusterer option enabled, and it is working fine. However when you click the cluster it shows the marker, but no title inside the popup window. What I would like to happen is for the link to the user next to the marker in the popup.

I've already read node/329281 and it was not helpful. I was also able to identify where in clusterer2.js to make the changes, I just need to know how to rewrite the function. Any suggestions?